# Oracle listagg on long value turned into strange characters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, listagg

I have a `VARCHAR2` column with the length set to 4000 CHAR. I inserted 1 row with 4000 Chinese characters, but when I run the SQL the result is very strange:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(VAL, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SEQ) FROM TBL GROUP BY ID;
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkSnd.png)

The data is `一二三四五六七八九十` repeated 400 times to make 4000 characters.
Since this ID has only 1 row I expect the exact same value as I inserted.
The first part looks fine but after some characters (around 2000 I think) the characters turned into some strange characters.

The database version is 12c.

Comment: Could you share your code for inserting the data too? And what your NLS_CHARACTERSET is? There's a [4000-byte hard limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57573908/3061852) so I'm curious how you inserted 4000 multi-byte characters.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely has to do with SQL Developer supporting multi-byte characters. I would try upgrading SQL Developer and the version of Java on your machine to the latest version and see if you are still having the issues. I am running SQL Developer 20.2 and Java 8 update 231 and am not seeing any issues when returning a large `LISTAGG` of the characters you specified.